# How to keep dropdown menu visible when hovering out of its parent li

Tags: css

I created a simple navigation. How do I keep the dropdown menu visible when hovering out of its parent li element? The only thing I could think of is by padding to the parent li when hovering, but I don't want that because that would change the height of the nav. Thanks!

```css
.topMenuSubMenu{
    display: none;
    background: red;
}

nav a:hover ~ .topMenuSubMenu{
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
}

nav > ul{
    display: flex;
}
nav > ul li{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
nav > ul li ul{
    margin-right: 50px;
} 
a:hover{
 color: #FFCC11;
}
nav a:hover{
color:#f4473a !important; 
}
nav a{
 color: white;
}
nav{
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <ul class="topMenuSubMenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 1 Sublink 1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/#">Llink 2</a>
            <ul class="topMenuSubMenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Llink 2 Sublink 1 </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Llink 2 Sublink 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Llink 2 Sublink 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Llink 2 Sublink 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your show/hide on the `<li>` not on the `<a>`. So change your rule to this instead:

```
nav li:hover .topMenuSubMenu{
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help!